# ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.esapi.waf.ESAPIWebApplicationFirewallFilter while applying ESAPIWebApplicationFirewallFilter

Tags: java, security, filter, esapi

Web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ESAPI-WAF</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.owasp.esapi.waf.ESAPIWebApplicationFirewallFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>log_settings</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j-waf.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>configuration</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/waf-policy.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ESAPI-WAF</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Error while Running on server:**

```
Jun 01, 2015 5:02:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter ESAPI-WAF
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.esapi.waf.ESAPIWebApplicationFirewallFilter
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5546)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the library you are using is not in applications classpath at runtime. Please be sure to add the JAR File of that library in

```
<WEBAPP>/WEB-INF/lib
```

or put it into your web containers library directory. For example in case of Apache Tomcat put that JAR file into

```
<CATALINA_HOME>/lib
```

directory and don't forget to restart the container or redeploy your application to take effect of that change.